# Implicitly convert value through a factory method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class

```
class Rational {
    ...
    public static Rational FromDouble(double d)
    ...
}
```

I am using factory methods because if I convert it from NaN, +inf, or -inf, I want to return a special value which may be reused.

I would like to be able to do

```
Rational r = 0d;
```

But to define an implicit conversion, I have to use a constructor, no? And if I use a constructor, there's no way to return e.g. `Rational.NaN`, I will have to return an actually-new rational. Is there a workaround or a layer to add that would make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an `implicit` conversion operator and that will do this for you.

```
public static implicit operator Rational(double d) => 
  new Rational(d); // or `FromDouble(d)`
```

You might also consider making `Rational` a `struct`.